# How can I import my own .class file into a RingoJS application?

Tags: java, ringojs

Good day,

I would like to know how I could import and call my library contained in a .jar file directly through RingoJS.

Thank you.

**Edit**:

Here is some additional informations. I have compiled a class named `xsltProcessor` that uses the `SAXON` library into a `.JAR` file. That class has a method named `transform( xml file source, xslt file source )`. That is the class and method I would like to use in RingoJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll have to add your library (the `.jar` file) to the classpath, either via Java's classpath or via adding it at runtime from within Ringo, using `addToClasspath`. See Ringo's [Java integration wiki page](http://ringojs.org/wiki/Java_integration) for more detail.

Then, you can just use the classes contained within that library using Rhino's `Packages.<java.package.name>` and related features for scripting Java. Read Rhino's [Scripting Java documentation](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/ScriptingJava.html) for the details.

Comment: This works! Any reason why I get a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` ? Is there anything special my class should inherit or implement?